# Ajax cannot display the response from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know that this question is already answered a lot, but even the previous responses from php are working, this response cannot work and i cannot find the reason for this issue. 
Although php was send the response succesfully, ajax cannot display without refreshing the page first. 
Here is my jquery.ajax code in the file `helpers.js`:

```
function likeButton(commentId, userId) {
$.ajax({
  url: "requests.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    like: "likeUp",
    commentId: commentId,
    userId: userId
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $("#comment_body").append(response);
  }
});
  }
```

Here is my php code in requests.php:

```
 if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
  if($_POST['like'] == "likeUp") {
    $commentId = $_POST['commentId'];
    $userId = $_POST['userId'];

    $sql = "SELECT gaming_comment_like FROM gaming_comments WHERE gaming_comment_id='$commentId'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $gaming_comment_like = $row['gaming_comment_like'];
    }
    $gaming_comment_like = $gaming_comment_like + 1;

    $sql_update = "UPDATE gaming_comments SET gaming_comment_like='$gaming_comment_like' WHERE gaming_comment_id='$commentId'";
    $result_update = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_update);
    exit();
  }
}
```

here is the eventhandler that calling the `likeButton` function, which is in a php file:

```
<p><img src='like.png' class='like_button' onclick='likeButton(".$gaming_comment_id.", ".$user_id.");'>$gaming_comment_like</p>";
```

Comment: Your PHP code does not generate any response for your javascript to display.

Comment: What is the actual response you're expecting from this AJAX request?  What is the runtime value of the `response` variable in your `success` callback?  What were you expecting it to be?  Why?

Comment: You are returning nothing.  So that looks like a fail.

Comment: you should print or echo the result of query  -  `echo json_encode($result_update);` to get the response on js side

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: @David you are right, but this exactly code i used in previous ajax responses and it worked. So what is the solution for that?  i tried it to echo to get the response on js side but is not working.

Comment: @NikolasBlues: The "solution" for what, exactly?  If your PHP code isn't *creating* any output, then what are you expecting to happen?  What are you trying to do?  If you want your PHP code to output something then, well *output something*.  `echo` something.

Comment: i understand your point and you are right David, i'm not output anything. I expected from php to assign +1 to the variable  $gaming_comment_like and send this response to ajax. I used this exactly code in a previous ajax-php responses and it worked. Sorry for asking but i don't know what to print from php because i wanted only to assign +1 to the variable that you saw.

Comment: @NikolasBlues: Well, if you want to get the value of `$gaming_comment_like` returned from your AJAX, then `echo $gaming_comment_like;` seems like a reasonable approach.  When you say: *"I used this exactly code in a previous ajax-php responses and it worked."* - Well, define "worked".  This code *doesn't output anything*.  By design.  So there's no way "this exact code" ever output anything in another context.

Comment: @David yes you are totally right. I echo $gaming_comment_like and now it works. When i said it worked in a previous ajax-php responses i was definetely false, because these previous responses with the exact same code didn't work with ajax, because the displaying of the results was happened in a different page and so after refreshing the page. Thank you David and sorry for my misunderstanding.